# Why does "Move on" (2012) seem so disjointed?

Tags: plot-explanation, move-on

I just had the doubtful pleasure of watching the 2012 film 'Move On'. It is described as "*special road movie*" on the film's [official website](http://move-on-film.com/#!movie/intl_movie/index.html) and an "*unusual road trip [with] unexpected turns*" on [imdb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2273326/).

Here's a short breakdown (with the revealing end)

> The main character Marc (Mads Mikkelsen) receives a suitcase with unknown content. His 'last job' is to deliver the suitcase. But it turns out to be not this easy (suprise?). He travels through countries, cars get trashed, shots get fired, nothing out of the ordinary. At the end he throws the suitcase in a hole.

For me it really seemed like they just cut some random scenes from an action movie with no real story whatsoever. **Am I totally missing something? Or is the story really just crap?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking at is the metaphorical [camel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_committee), a horse designed by a committee. The film "[Move on](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Move_On_(2012_film))" was a crowd-sourced experimental movie that incorporated scenes, clips and elements from nearly 1200 contributors including 8 major film "segments" that were woven into the pre-existing plotline:

> From pre-production through to the shooting of the film, cinema buffs
>   from 11 European countries had the opportunity to actively shape
>   elements of the road movie. They were involved in aspects ranging from
>   designing the posters and performing in minor supporting parts or as
>   extras. Several thousand people applied online, submitting their film
>   clips and sound recordings for assessment. The best contributions were
>   incorporated into Move On, thus giving the film a unique character,
>   and many of the winners were even on set during filming.

When combined with the relative inexperience of the principals (actors, director and crew) and the fact that the film was [heavily sponsored by a number of corporations](http://www.myfilmviews.com/2013/01/12/move-on-2012/) (all of whom insisted on input into the plot) you can easily see how this sort of [project](http://www.move-on-film.com/) could lead to something less polished than a normal indie film

Comment: The cynic in me says that they included as many "fan-sponsors" as possible in order to maximise the amount of money donated.

Comment: I think the realist in me agrees. Thanks for the answer :)